# HTTP Authorization in SOAP delphi

Tags: web-services, delphi, soap, authorization, delphi-7

I am trying to send a request to web service,
this is the WSDL:
http://www.smsmelli.com/class/sms/webservice/server.php?wsdl

after long researching I underestand untyped array should replace with array of array of string;
till here, it solved, but I realize my SOAP doesn't work properly.
I check PHP action that works exactly same, then I find it sets Credential in Authentication in the header of HTTP from SOAP;

```
in WireShark:
-HyperText Transfer Protocol
--Authorization: Basic Y3LIZ577838sdf=
---Credentials: YourUserName:YourPassWord
```

how can I set that in Delphi 7 with HTTPRIO SOAP?

Comment: The generated WSDL doesn't even compile because of: function  GetCredit: Array; // <== Identifier expected but 'ARRAY' found

Comment: dear Gonzalez, that problem solved by replacing with array of array of string. but i say why is delphi unable? how can i set HTTP HEADER? or in this case, Credentials?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about Delphi 7, but in XE2 the THTTPRIO has a HTTPWebNode property, which has settings for username and password.

In the BeforePost of the HTTPWebNode you can do detailed manipulation of the HTTP headers, like:

```
procedure TFrmTestEWS.HTTPRIO1HTTPWebNode1BeforePost(
  const HTTPReqResp: THTTPReqResp; Data: Pointer);
const
   CONTENT_HEADER_EX2010 = 'Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8';
begin
   // http://forum.delphi-treff.de/archive/index.php/t-31817.html
   // Need to exchange the Content-Type Header, because Exchange 2010 expects
   // 'Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8' instead of
   // 'Content-Type: text/xml; charset="utf-8"' which is RFC conform and used by XE2
   HttpAddRequestHeaders(Data, PChar(CONTENT_HEADER_EX2010), Length(CONTENT_HEADER_EX2010), HTTP_ADDREQ_FLAG_REPLACE);
end;
```

Hope this helps
Jan

Comment: actully, in delphi 7 that code works, but not well. nothing happens, please watch this: http://i45.tinypic.com/1zobya9.jpg

Comment: Can you in the debugger trace what's going on?