# Send credentials in SOAP header

Tags: authentication, delphi, soap, header

I'm trying to develop a small program in Delphi xe10.3 to get data from a web service using SOAP.

The WSDL is https://www1.gsis.gr/wsaade/RgWsPublic2/RgWsPublic2?WSDL.
I did import it into Delphi.

The problem I’m facing is that I couldn’t find a working way to pass the credentials (basic authentication) into request header even I did use some methods I found on the web. The service responds that there are not credentials into request.

I want to mention that this is my first try to use SOAP technology and I have been confused. It will be appreciated if someone could help me to resolve this issue.

The code is :

```
procedure TForm1.EchoClick(Sender: TObject);
 var   Service  : RgWsPublic2Service_Interface;
       httpRio : THTTPRIO;
       inpr : rg_ws_public2_input_rtType2;
       ddate : TXSDate;
       ReturnInfo : Result;
       AskedInfo  : rg_ws_public2_basic_rtType2;
       ErrorStr : string;
begin
  httpRio    := THTTPRIO.Create(nil);
  ReturnInfo := Result.Create;
  ddate      := TXSdate.Create;
  ddate.AsDate := date;
  inpr         := rg_ws_public2_input_rtType2.Create;
  inpr.afm_called_by  := ed_myAfm.Text;
  inpr.afm_called_for := ed_ClientAfm.Text;
  inpr.as_on_date     := ddate;

  httpRio.HTTPWebNode.UserName := Ed_usname.Text;
  httpRio.HTTPWebNode.Password := Ed_pass.Text;

  Service    := GetRgWsPublic2Service_Interface(true,'',httpRio);
  ReturnInfo := Service.rgWsPublic2AfmMethod(inpr);

  ErrorStr := ReturnInfo.rg_ws_public2_result_rtType.error_rec.error_code+' / '+
              ReturnInfo.rg_ws_public2_result_rtType.error_rec.error_descr;

  if ErrorStr <> '' then
  begin
    memo1.Lines.Add('Error!!!!');
    memo1.Lines.Add(ErrorStr);
  end
  else
  begin
    memo1.Lines.Text := ReturnInfo.rg_ws_public2_result_rtType.ToString;

    AskedInfo  := ReturnInfo.rg_ws_public2_result_rtType.basic_rec;
    EdEnterpriceName.Text := AskedInfo.onomasia;
    mm_DoyInfo.Text       := AskedInfo.doy+' / '+AskedInfo.doy_descr;
  end;
  ReturnInfo.Destroy;
  ddate.Destroy;
end;
```

Comment: Isn't the answer to this question (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14174853/http-authorization-in-soap-delphi) what you are looking for?

Comment: The above answer does not help me. Why the following code does not work ? Can't be used to send the credentials by Soap header? 
 httpRio.HTTPWebNode.UserName := Ed_usname.Text; httpRio.HTTPWebNode.Password := Ed_pass.Text;

Comment: For this service, you need to define the soap headers with this xsd: docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd, unfortunately I no longer use delphi.